# How do I compare a huge amount of strings against the beginning of another?

Tags: php, string, foreach, match

I have two tables. One with a load of numbers. I then have another table with a list of prefixes( 30, 000+ ).

I need to loop through the prefixes and see if any of the numbers in table 1 starts with any of the prefixes.

This is what I have so far.

```
$tdata = $r->get_t_data(); //array of prefix
/*
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [prefix] => 101
        [dest] => UK
    )

)
 */

$cdata = $r->get_c_data(); //array of number

/*Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [row] => 1
        [num] => 441143610120
    )

)*/

$temp = array();
$i=0;
$time=0;
foreach ($cdata as $ckey => $c) {


    foreach ($tdata as $tkey => $t) {


        $length = strlen($t['prefix']);

        if (strpos($c['num'], $t['prefix'], 0, $length )) {

            $temp[$i]['row']=$c['row'];
            $temp[$i]['prefix']=$t['prefix'];
            $temp[$i]['dialled']=$c['num'];
            $temp[$i]['dest']=$t['dest'];

            break;

        $i++; //increment only if found
        }

    }

    $time++;

}
```

so basically it loops through the numbers and then I try and match the first part of the number with the prefix.

At the moment it is returning and empty array.

Hope you can help

Comment: You could solve your problem when you pull your data out of the database by joining the tables

Comment: I would rather do it that way but couldn't figure out how to match first part of string

Comment: I've added an answer where it shows you how to do it in a join. If you give me the schema of your tables I can customize it more to fit your columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to do the join in your sql as opposed to checking after in your PHP.  To do a join with a like you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table t JOIN prefixTable p ON t.num LIKE CONCAT(p.prefix, '%')
```

The key is `LIKE CONCAT(p.prefix, '%')` that's saying combine the tables where `t.num` is like `prefix%`and in MySQL `%` is a wildcard since we didn't put a wild card at the front that means that the `t.num` column has to START with prefix

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `if (strpos($c['num'], $t['prefix'], 0, $length ))` can return 0, which php will interpret as false. strpos should be checked like this:

```
if (false !== strpos($c['num'], $t['prefix'], 0, $length )) {}
```

Comment: Or, if the prefix is always at the beginning, `if (strpos($c['num'], $t['prefix'], 0, $length ) === 0)`

Comment: even though the prefix is always more than 1 character?

Comment: strpos returns the index of the first character of the matched substring, so length is irrelevant. If the first character of $needle is the first character of $haystack, strpos will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

use [preg_grep](http://php.net/preg_grep) to reduce the amount of looping/search code you have:

```
foreach ($table1 as $search) {
    $safe_search = preg_quote($search);
    $matches = preg_grep("/^$safe_search/", $prefix_array);
    if (count($matches) > 0) {
       echo "Found $search in the prefix array\n";
    }
}
```